# Missing reference to Microsoft Office Web Components 11

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I have an old vba project that I'm trying to bring up to speed.

I'm running windows 7 64 bit, with office 2010, so of course I'm missing some reference.

In particular my issue is a reference to Microsoft Office Web Components 11.0

I can't remove the reference since it is "in use"

I've tried to manually download the file (owc11.dll) and copy it to system32 and register it using regsvr32 owc11.dll (it said it registerede, but it's still missing in the project).

What do I do to resolve this?

Comment: Did you browse to the dll from the references dialog? Note: if you have 64 bit Office, you can't use it.

Comment: yeah, I attempted to remove it or change the path via download,but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried deleting whichever OWC control(s) are in the workbook, then changing the reference, and adding the controls back?

Comment: thanks for your reply Rory - I really appreciate it - I'm sorry for asking this, but how do I identify the OWC controls, it's a project that I've taken over from a colleague, so I have no idea how it's put together :)

Comment: You'd be looking for Spreadsheet, Chart, Pivot Table and Data Control objects on one or more userforms.

Comment: I'm afraid it's more than userforms. It breaks in the code of the modules also, since there are explicit OWC11. object references

Comment: But removing the objects on the userforms should allow you to uncheck the reference and then reset it to your downloaded dll.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105155/discussion-between-jakob-and-rory).